# Tortoise SVN update error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate and TortoiseSVN 1.6.12. When I try to do and SVN update on my project root, i get the following error:

```
Can't open file 
'\path\to\directory\.svn\lock': 
The system cannot open the file.
```

When I update this problem directory directly it works, but when I try updating the root it fails. The error happens with different files from time to time. I've tried deleting the problem directory and then restoring it with an update, and then trying update on the root again, but that didn't help. Also, there's no file called 'lock' in .svn directory. I've explored the repo too and there are no duplicate files (that is with the same name and different case).

I would be glad to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the .svn dir in your root dir? have you tried svn clean on root dir? have a look at http://thedrupalblog.com/resolving-subversion-svnlock-permission-denied-issue. Also, if possible, use a dvcs like mercurial